# Second wifi router for abg traffic

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I've got a D-Link dir-655 hooked into a Comcast cable connection. I'm told I should make that exclusively N and get a cheap abg router for abg traffic (wii, iphone). Do I just hook the second router to a network port on the dir-655 and set up it's own dns?

Comment: Why would you need to differentiate DNS between the two? and no, if you don't configure DHCP/NAT properly between them, two routers hooked up like that will render your entire network useless.

Comment: I'd like them to be two separate networks so that I can take non N traffic away from the N router. What's the best plan?

Comment: Configure one as an access point only, connect it to the main router, connect all N devices to the N AP, and all ABG devices to the ABG AP. Having them be actual separate networks is probably not what you really want, and is a lot more work.

Comment: I have a cable modem and one router now. Are you saying I'll need 2 more AP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did a single router and so far, so good. The easiest option worked.